# Warning: Creating default object from empty value in admin.php on line 52

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to all of this.  After finding a wordpress theme that I really like I get the following error:  Creating default object from empty value in /home/**sitename**/public_html/wp-content/themes/**themename**/library/admin/theme-admin.php on line 52

This is the code on line 52 of the file.

```
/* Create the theme settings page. */
$framework->settings_page = add_theme_page( $theme->get( 'Name' ) .  __( ' Theme Settings', $domain ), __( 'Theme Settings', $domain ), 'edit_theme_options', 'theme-settings', array( &$this, 'framework_settings_page' ) );
```

I removed the theme and reinstalled but am still getting the same error.  I have not yet installed plugins besides aksimet.

I'm very new to all of this so please bear with me if this has been asked and answered before.  I have gone through numerous posts but I don't want to mess up the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this an error printed at the top of your browser window or the kind of error that crashes Wordpress and will not display your site? Have you brought it up with the theme's author (especially if the latter kind of error is what you are dealing with)?

Comment: It's a very bad start, look for another theme. In one line: using `&$this` is an outdated PHP4 style and `__('',$domain)` is wrong.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be interfering with my site when I do a live preview right now but I am afraid that it may cause issues further down the line! I have submitted a query on the site where I downloaded the theme so waiting for a response there as well.

Comment: thanks brasofilo.  just what I was thinking.  i don't want to continue making changes and then having a problem further down the line!